# Size of selected dot in pagecontroller

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to change size of selected dot in pagecontroller.
Is there any way to change it? I need to subclass pagecontroller? But i use PageViewConttroller

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reference that you can do, whatever the customization.

**>** OC     [tapagecontrol](https://github.com/TanguyAladenise/TAPageControl)

**>** Swift  [scpagecontrol](https://github.com/myoungsc/SCPageControl)

[image]

Comment: May i use it in objective-c?

Comment: You're welcome..... :) you should accept correct answer as per stackoverflow guideline so that other people can get help having same issue!  @DenisKosov

Comment: It isn't yet. I use UIPageViewController and there's a lot of things to remake.